# Chrome does not execute js properly but firefox does it

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, cross-browser

Sorry for my english. Correct me if I wrong.
This function execute properly in firefox but target browser is chrome and I dont know what's wrong

**myjs.js**

```
function addProduct(order_id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: $("#formProducts").serialize(),
    url: "/save/" + order_id,
    complete: function(){}
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/add/product/" + order_id,
    complete: function(){
      window.location.reload()
    },
  });
}
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request: HttpRequest, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(id=int(kwargs['order_id']))
        try:
            comment = Comment.objects.get(order=order)
            comment.text = request.POST['comment']
        except Exception as _:
            comment = Comment(text="", order=order)
        comment.save()
        for key, val in request.POST.items():
            if "status" in key:
                idp = int(key.split("status")[1])
                product = Product.objects.get(id=idp)
                product.status = val
                product.save()
            elif "provider" in key:
                idp = int(key.split("provider")[1])
                product = Product.objects.get(id=idp)
                product.provider = val
                product.save()
            elif "med" in key:
                idp = int(key.split("med")[1])
                product = Product.objects.get(id=idp)
                product.name = val
                product.save()
            elif "amount" in key:
                idp = int(key.split("amount")[1])
                product = Product.objects.get(id=idp)
                product.amount = val
                product.save()
            elif "cost" in key:
                idp = int(key.split("cost")[1])
                product = Product.objects.get(id=idp)
                product.cost = val
                product.save()
            elif "ITOG" in key:
                order.summary = val
                order.save()
        url_ref = request.session["url_ref"]
        return redirect(url_ref)

def addProduct(request: HttpRequest, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=int(order_id))
    product = Product(name="", amount=1, cost=0.0, order=order)
    product.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Function must collect formdata and post it. Then make get request and reload page. Chrome does it but I don't see saved data after reload page, I have to reload page again and then I see save data.

Thanks halcyon. Your answer is right

Comment: I doubt this is a browser issue. I think it's a timing issue. It's possible the 2nd request completes before the 1st one. The page will reload and the 1st request is aborted. You can solve it by reloading the page when _both_ requests finish.

Comment: Halcyon, thank you for your fast and right answer. I solved my problem as you adviced

Answer (score -1):

You can use this structure

```
 $(document).on('click','.sendwork',function(e){
       $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: $("#formProducts").serialize(),
        url: "/save/" + order_id,
        complete: function(){}
      });
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/add/product/" + order_id,
        complete: function(){
        },
      });
      window.location.reload()
    });
```

Comment: Terrible solution. Now you abort _both_ requests.